# find_in_batches: how to end at a particular id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a million records and I want to process 100k at a time through 10 different workers.

Documentation:

> "You can control the starting point for the batch processing by
>   supplying the :start option. This is especially useful if you want
>   multiple workers dealing with the same processing queue. You can make
>   worker 1 handle all the records between id 0 and 10,000 and worker 2
>   handle from 10,000 and beyond (by setting the :start option on that
>   worker)."

How to do the above when we can only supply the `:start` option but not a `:end` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find_in_batches will iterate through all the records and yield them to the block in batches.

> "The size of each batch is set by the :batch_size option; the default
>   is 1000."

So set a `:batch_size` of 100000, and then you will need to put in your code to assign each batch to your worker.  So something like this:

```
i = 0
Model.find_in_batches(batch_size: 100000) do |batch|
  # code to assign batch to worker i
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I wasn't super clear. I want 10 different processes to work on that queue. With what you suggested I believe it would just process 100k records 10 times serially. I want these records to be processed in parallel.

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully it is a little more helpful.  I'm not sure how you were planning on assigning the batches to the workers.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray for symmetry, there is now a [finish param](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html):

> find_each(start: nil, finish: nil, batch_size: 1000, error_on_ignore: nil)
>
> :finish - Specifies the primary key value to end at, inclusive of the value.

[Pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12257)